# Block diagram reduction. Can someone check my steps?

Tags: block-diagram

[image]

I have an exam coming up. I want to make sure I'm doing things correctly. Thanks for your help

Comment: `Can someone check my steps?` is not a question about the diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just your final step was wrong: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir. Highly appreciated

Comment: @Majid If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.